# DOCKER CONTAINER ID is not getting displayed

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows and when I was running the docker command on windows PowerShell but I am not able to see the `CONTAINER ID` and `CONTAINER NAME`.

COMMAND: `docker ps -a`

Can someone please tell what will be the command for that?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run `docker ps -a`? Do you get an error? Do you see some information, but simply not what you expect?

Comment: I am not getting the error but I am not able to see the information like container name or id etc

Comment: What *do* you get? If you see headings like `CONTAINER ID` , `IMAGE` etc, but nothing else, then you have no containers, either running or stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Please click on the Docker desktop icon on the right bottom corner of your desktop as shown below.

[image]

The Docker desktop ui should show all of the live as well as exited container.

[image]

Runa a sample nginx container and check the correctness of your installation.

docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web nginx

Check if you are able to see newly created nginx container named web on the dockerdesktop ui.

[image]

If you can see the newly created nginx container then your installation is correct. Now run your container from the command line and observe the Dockerdesktop UI.

If nginx container doesn't start then your docker installation is having the problem. Please do a clean uninstall and follow the steps

ReInstall Docker Desktop on Windows using below steps:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

Comment: @arjungoel1995 what exactly did resolve your issue.

Comment: I have opened a new Powershell thread and simultaneously I ran the `docker ps -a` command on other shell and once I got that CONTAINER ID, I was able to start and stop it. I am using Windows 10 Home. I don't know whether it works on Linux and Mac easily.